# ¿Cómo cambiar los border en los input search usando el appearance?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

¿Se puede cambiar algunos atributos usando el ícono de lupa que sale usando  `appearance: searchfield;`?
Por ejemplo, los quería cambiar los border 1px y que sea redondeado como usando border-radius:15px o tener más configuración de estilo css.

Pongo ejemplo:

```css
input[type="search"]
{
    max-width: 375px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: gray;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    line-height: 15px;
}

input[type="search"]{
    padding-left: 20px;
    appearance: searchfield;
    -moz-appearance: searchfield;
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield;

}
```

```html
 <input type="search" name="" id="" >
```

¿Hay otro modo mejor o de otras formas para poner un ícono de lupa búsqueda y poder poner más estilos propios como los border redondeados o poner color? Solo me deja los padding interior y el ancho, porque al poner el appearance searchfield solo me sale la lupa y no me deja configurar más.

Comment: No termino de entender, ¿a qué tratas de ponerle los bordes?

Comment: usando esta propiedad appearance:searchfiel no te deja de poner y cambiar los border ni de color ni ponerlo redondeado